# FInding the shortest path between nodes, and whether a graph is connected

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

obviously below is a homework problem. I can't understand anything my professor is saying so I don't even need to know where to start looking for the information required to find the answer to this question. If you could give me some leads about where to learn about this stuff as well as how you might approach solving this problem I would be grateful.

In the following graph, find the shortest path between two nodes - your choice, but make the problem interesting.

Is this a connected graph?

[image]

Comment: I would read my notes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis To be honest with you, I rarely find my lecture notes useful. Most of the time I use online tutorials or youtube videos to expands on the topics from my notes, as most of the time they're just a summary of what the lecturer has said during the lecture.

Comment: Also Google for `graph shortest path` and read some of the search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be preferable first to know how the graph is represented in memory. If it was up to you, you can use a 2d array as that's the simplest way to represent weighted edges.

The easiest to implement shortest path algorithm is probably Djikstra's which is slightly slower but less complicated than A*. To use Djikastra's you want to first implement a priority queue. In Java there's a PriorityQueue class or you'll have to implement it yourself otherwise. After that, the implementation should be fairly straightforward using pseudo-code that's available on Wikipedia or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

you should use A star algorithm to find the shortest path between two nodes.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star

you can tell if it is connecting using Menger's theorem 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem

---